# MongoDB - overhead on collections vs databases

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference in overhead for MongoDB databases versus collections? When is it better to use more collections or more databases? My debate is whether or not to use a new database for each user for an application. From the naive standpoint, I am leaning towards using a database per user for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Database have greater physical separation, this makes them easier to separate and replicate/shard separately. However, your use case is normally a NOOOOOOOO, however, it does depend on the app, what exactly are you building?

Comment: I am building an app where the users will never interact, so the databases might as well be separate, methinks

Comment: It might be ok but if you don't require the separation for the above reasons I mentioned (sharding etc) the extra overhead of the database files etc could make you think twice

Comment: Having multiple databases for one application comes with it's own problems. You need multiple datasources, which in turn will create a separate connection pool. And that's only one problem. My rule of thumb is: as long as data belongs to an application it goes to a collection in a database logically attached to the application. I have never had a problem with that. But I have seen a lot of problems when people had different datasources for one application.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg remember pooling is driver dependant, PHP driver does not do it anymore

Comment: well, if my application has 50 users using the app at once. those 50 users could be hitting different collections in the same database, or different collections in different databases.

Comment: @sammaye: thanks, another point against php. Alex: they sure can but why add a layer - however small it is - of complexity? Remember KISS.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg any language used in a non-asynch manner will result in pooling being useless per process

Comment: @sammaye: huh? How that? If each process gets the connection of a shared pool? Like in a Factory pattern?